# Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false

Tags: plugin-development

I'm coding a plugin. When it's loaded I check is_single() which returns the following error:

```
_doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false.' ), '3.1.0' );
```

Where can I find the WP initializing process documentation?

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Where and how are you calling `is_single()`? When a plugins file is loaded the query hasn't run or even been created yet, the theme hasn't even been fully loaded, it's far too early to do those kinds of checks ( it may not even be a browser request!  Cron jobs, WP CLI, AJAX, REST API etc etc ). What are you trying to do in a plugin that requires `is_single`? Context will help iin guiding you to the appropriate hook/time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where can I find the WP initializing process documentation?

[This](https://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview) should help:

> So, here are the steps WordPress uses to decide what posts or pages to
> display on a page, and display them:
>
> 1. When a visitor first clicks on or types a URL for a page that is part of your blog, WordPress starts by running a few core files
>    (`wp-config.php`, `wp-settings.php`, etc.) If you are interested in
>    the specifics of the file loading order, start at `index.php` and
>    follow the chain of files as each PHP file includes/requires
>    additional PHP files (or read [this excellent post at
>    humanshell.net](http://humanshell.net/wordpress/wordpress-initialization/))
> 2. WordPress loads and initializes any plugins you have activated (calls the plugin `init` actions).
> 3. WordPress loads the "text domain" for internationalization, and the `functions.php` file from the currently active theme.
> 4. WordPress runs the `wp()` function (in `wp-includes/functions.php`), which calls `$wp->main()` (`$wp` is an
>    object of class `WP`, which is defined in `wp-includes/class-wp.php`).
>    This tells WordPress to:
>
>    1. Parse the URL into a query specification using `WP->parse_request()` -- more on that
>       [below](https://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview#More_on_WP-.3Eparse_request.28.29).
>    2. Set all the `is_` variables that are used by [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)
>       using `$wp_query->parse_query()` (`$wp_query` is an object of class
>       `WP_Query`, which is defined in `wp-includes/query.php`). Note that in
>       spite of this function's name, in this case `WP_Query->parse_query`
>       doesn't actually do any parsing for us, since that is done before-hand
>       by `WP->parse_request()`.
>    3. Convert the query specification into a MySQL database query, and run the database query to get the list of posts, in function
>       `WP_Query->get_posts()`. Save the posts in the `$wp_query` object to
>       be used in the WordPress Loop.
>    4. Handle 404 errors.
>    5. Send the blog's HTTP headers.
>    6. Set up some variables for the WordPress Loop.

So generally, on the front-end (non `wp-admin` side), you can call the conditional tags like `is_single()` only on or after the [`parse_query` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_query/) and later hooks like [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/), [`wp`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/), [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/), [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) and [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) (yes, they are in that order).

Therefore if for example you used an early hook like [`plugins_loaded`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/) like so, then you'd get the error in question:

```php
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function () {
    error_log( is_single() );
} );
```

So I hope this answer *helps you find the right hook*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a really complete answer

Comment: I'm glad I could help , but I forgot to state that the `WP_Query` class is actually defined in `wp-includes/class-wp-query.php`, but prior to WordPress 4.7 (Dec 2016..), it's indeed in `wp-includes/query.php`.